# Web scraping - how to access content rendered in JavaScript via Angular.js?

Tags: python, angularjs, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape data from the public site [asx.com.au](http://www.asx.com.au)

The page http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/company.do#!/ACB/details contains a `div` with class 'view-content', which has the information I need:

[image]

But when I try to view this page via Python's `urllib2.urlopen` that div is empty:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/company.do#!/ACB/details'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
contentDiv = soup.find("div", {"class": "view-content"})
print(contentDiv)

# the results is an empty div:
# <div class="view-content" ui-view=""></div>
```

Is it possible to access the contents of that div programmatically?

Edit: as per the comment it appears that the content is rendered via `Angular.js`. Is it possible to trigger the rendering of that content via Python?

Comment: I see `ng-scope` - it is name use by framework `AngularJS` (or similar framework) so this page is generated by JavaScript.

Comment: @furas given that, perhaps this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673447/fetch-text-from-web-with-angular-js-tags-such-as-ng-view and I need to use Selenium or similar?

Comment: you don't need selenium you already has url in my answer and you can get it using `urrlib` and `json` :) I'm working on code example.

Comment: @furas You can't use ng.probe when a site is in production mode

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This page use `JavaScript` to read data from server and fill page.

I see you use developer tools in `Chrome` - see in tab `Network` on `XHR` or `JS` requests.

I found this url:

http://data.asx.com.au/data/1/company/ACB?fields=primary_share,latest_annual_reports,last_dividend,primary_share.indices&callback=angular.callbacks._0

This url gives all data almost in JSON format

But if you use this link without `&callback=angular.callbacks._0` then you get data in pure JSON format and you will could use `json` module to convert it to python dictionary.

---

**EDIT:** working code

```
import urllib2
import json

# new url      
url = 'http://data.asx.com.au/data/1/company/ACB?fields=primary_share,latest_annual_reports,last_dividend,primary_share.indices'

# read all data
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

# convert json text to python dictionary
data = json.loads(page)

print(data['principal_activities'])
```

Output:

```
Mineral exploration in Botswana, China and Australia.
```

---

**EDIT (2020.12.23)**

This answer is almost 5 years old and was created for Python2. Now in Python3 it would need `urllib.request.urlopen()` or `requests.get()` but real problem is that for 5 years this page changed structure and technologie. Urls (in question and answer) don't exists any more. This page would need new analyze and new method.

In question was url

http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/company.do#!/ACB/details

but currently page uses url

https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/company/acb

And it use different urls for `AJAX`,`XHR`

https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/acb/about
https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/acb/announcements
https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/acb/key-statistics
etc.

You can find more urls using `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`)

```
import urllib.request
import json

# new url      
url = 'https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/acb/about'

# read all data
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

# convert json text to python dictionary
data = json.loads(page)

print(data['data']['description'])
```

Output:

```
Minerals exploration & development
```

Comment: Many thanks for the fast and detailed response! This is awesome.

Comment: in new url you have to use other firm name in place of `ACB` and you get data for this firm

Comment: That XHR comment saved me. Amazing.  Good job.

Comment: @furas what if the website being scraped has a login/pw, how would `urllib2` handle that?

Comment: @Raj currently I use `requests` for scraping. Generally you have to send `POST` request with login/password and get `cookie` which you have to use with other requests. Page may also send other values for security reason so first you may have to get page with login form and get hidden values. I always start with `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see all values in all requests. Sometimes page uses JavaScript to generate values and it is easier to do all with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  which can control web browser.

Comment: not working in python3 as urllib2 isnot support python3 and urllib3 hasn't any urlopen method.

Comment: @ShahVipul this answer is almost 5 years old and was created when people was using mostly Python2. But in Python3 you have `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` - you can see it urllib2 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) `The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error.`. But you can use also `requests.get(url)` or anything else.

Comment: @ShahVipul I check code and there is bigger problem then `urllib2` - for 5 years this page changed structure and technologie. Urls (in question and answer) don't exists any more. This page would need new analyze and new method.