# Python Web Scraping - Is it not possible to scrape this site?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape the following website: `https://www.globenewswire.com/NewsRoom`

My goal is to store the press releases and articles in a database that I utilize later on. I've done this with other news sites too and deleted the code on here for easier readability (100% no influence on the code given to you). My problem is that I can't figure out how to exactly scrape headlines, links and other data since the html-code is structured with unusual attributes.

The following code is how I approached it. Maybe someone has an idea on what mistakes I did in scraping. Gladly appreciate any help.

```
import requests
import sqlite3
import Keywords
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


# ----- Initializing Database & Notification Service -----
connect = sqlite3.connect('StoredArticles.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()
print("Connection created.")


try:
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE articlestable (article_time TEXT, article_title TEXT, article_keyword TEXT, 
    article_link TEXT, article_description TEXT, article_entry_time DATETIME)''')
    cursor.execute('''CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_article_link ON articlestable(article_link)''')
except:
    pass
print("Table ready.")

while True:

    class Scrapers:

        # ----- Initialize Keywords -----
        def __init__(self):
            self.article_keyword = None
            self.article_title = None
            self.article_link = None
            self.article_time = None
            self.article_time_drop = None
            self.article_description = None
            self.article_entry_time = None
            self.headers = {
                'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)' +
                    'Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15'
            }

        def scraping_globenewswire(self, page):
            url = 'https://www.globenewswire.com/NewsRoom?page=' + str(page)
            r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

            articles = soup.select('.main-container > .row')
            print("GlobeNewswire - Scraping page " + str(page) + "...")
            sleep(randint(0, 1))

            for item in articles:
                self.article_title = item.select_one('a[data-autid="article-url"]').text.strip()
                self.article_time = item.select_one('span[data-autid="article-published-date"]').text.strip()
                self.article_link = 'https://www.globenewswire.com' + \
                                    item.select_one('a[data-autid="article-url"]')['href']
                self.article_description = item.select_one('span', _class='pagging-list-item-text-body').text.strip()
                self.article_entry_time = datetime.now()
                cursor.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO articlestable VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
                               (self.article_time, self.article_title, self.article_keyword, self.article_link,
                                self.article_description, self.article_entry_time))
                print(self.article_title)
            return


    # ----- End of Loops -----

    scraper = Scrapers()

    # ----- Range of Pages to scrape through -----
    for x in range(1, 3):
        scraper.scraping_globenewswire(x)


    # ----- Add to Database -----
    connect.commit()
    print("Process done. Starting to sleep again. Time: " + str(datetime.now()))
    sleep(randint(5, 12))
```

Comment: The website is not server-side rendered. You must use selenium or scrapy to scrape data from such websites.  Your question is different but the problem is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch text from web with Angular JS tags such as ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673447/fetch-text-from-web-with-angular-js-tags-such-as-ng-view)

Comment: You can also use `requests-html` for executing the JS

Comment: @crissal Could you give me an example how to do this? A line of code with the given website would already help a lot

Comment: @NiklasKlotz https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#javascript-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted all the headlines of page=1 from the given URL.

> The headlines are present inside an `<a>` with the attribue `data-autid` equals to `article-url`

- Select all the `<a>` with the above attributes using `findAll()`.
- Iterate over all the selected `<a>` above and extract the headlines i.e, text
- You can extend this and extract whatever data you need with this approach.

This code will print all the headlines of page=1 from the given URL.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.globenewswire.com/NewsRoom'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

headlines = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'data-autid': 'article-url'})

for i in headlines:
    print(i.text, end="\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me to solve my problem :)